# Why is this equation non-linear

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I came across this in my textbook. The author says this equation is nonlinear

$$m\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{t^2}}}x =  - {F_0}$$ for x<0
$$m\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{t^2}}}x = {F_0}$$ for x>0
$$m\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{t^2}}}x = 0$$for x=0.
But as far as I know, the linear differential equation must be a sum of terms each of which contains at most one power of x. It seems like it actually meets this standard. So how can I tell whether one equation is linear or nonlinear?

Comment: Note that the equation changes with the value of $x$ so you have discontinuities.

Comment: Because the equation is defined differently at different points in the domain.

Comment: @Annika Thank you very much

Comment: @H. sapiens rex thank you

Comment: If you want to stick to the definition, you can rewrite the equation:
$$m\partial_t^2(x) = -\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}_+^*}(x)F_0 + \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}_-^*}(x)F_0.$$ Since the indicator functions are not linear, your equation is not linear too.

Comment: @Gaetano That's exactly what I want to know, thank you

Comment: If you take $x_1$ and $x_2$ two solutions. Is $x_1+x_2$ a solution ? To answer that, you have to show that $x1+x_2$ is a solution. If you sum the LHS, you have $m\partial_t^2 (x_1+x_2)$, fine. However if  you sum inidicator function, this will not be the indicator function of the sum. This is more clear ? @Raffaella

Comment: @Gaetano Thank you very much ！This is far more clear!! Through your comment, I totally understand this question , thank you!

Comment: This is non-linear strictly because it is not homogenous. The fact that the particular function is discontinuous at $0$ is immaterial. Even a non-zero constant particular function (i.e., if $m\partial_t^2 x = F_0$ everywhere) would still make this a non-linear equation. However, the homogenous equation $m\partial_t^2 x =0$ is linear, and it is still true that if you can find even one solution to the particular equation, every solution can be obtained by adding solutions to the homogenous equation to it.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Sorry ,did I mix up the conception of linear differential equation and linear equation? Is there nonhomogeneous linear differential equation? So is the equation i  mentioned above  nonhomogeneous linear differential equation?

Comment: You weren't the one to call the equation "non-linear". We are just interpreting the statement the author made. But, in my experience, the equation is commonly called "linear" if the operator is linear, even when it is not homogenous. Perhaps a better description would be "affine", but I don't think I've ever seen it used in this context.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Thank you very much!!!!!